# what a client connection can I use for the game client?

Tags: java, http, servlets

I am using http servlet on my server.

My game client uses the next http connection:

```
InetAddress inteAddress = InetAddress.getByName(server);
SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(inteAddress, port);

// create a socket
socket = new Socket();

// this method will block no more than timeout ms.
int timeoutInMs = 10*1000;   // 10 seconds
socket.connect(socketAddress, timeoutInMs);
```

Time socket connection = 10 seconds... but I need to keep the connection

What a client connection can I use for the **game** client? (Looking for best practice)

Comment: If you are using Servlet at server then you can not expect to keep alive connection from client. Servlets are supposed to receive a request, process it, send response and disconnect from client. You need to create a Socket Server in your back end and implement a mechanism to keep alive the connection.

Comment: Thanks for the response, he approaches me

Answer (score 2):

As soon as your socket connection is established, you can keep it around and reuse it as you see fit.

The value for the `timeout` parameter only has effect *during establishment* of the connection. If it's 10 seconds, as in your example, the implementation will try to establish a connection for 10 seconds (the method call is blocked during that time). If the implementation fails to establish a connection within those 10 seconds, it will fail.